Identify this old movie about a benevolent Squirrel
Many many years ago, I saw an old movie or maybe just a portion of it where a miser (think Uncle Scrooge like) lived above a poor family.  He might have been their landlord, not sure.  He stashed his money by putting it into a cranny in a wall that happened to be near a family of squirrels.  The money was of no use to them so they got rid of it by tossing it out of another hole in the wall below them; right into the hands of the poor family.  That is all that I remember.  Can anyone tell me the title of this old film or any more about it?  It might have been a Christmas tale.

When was "many many years" ago and roughly how old might the movie have been?

I think the movie you are thinking of is the 1950 movie "The Great Rupert" (re-released in 2003 under the title "A Christmas Wish").
I found a blog that provides a description that matches your description:

At the end of her rope, Durante’s wife prays for some financial help from God, explaining that “Rosalinda needs shoes.” Just at that moment the miserly man next door thinks he is hiding his $1500 behind the wall, but a squirrel that lives in that wall space sees the money coming into its lair, so it throws the money out. Surprised and shocked, Durante’s wife sees hundred dollar bills coming down, and she figures the money is coming down from Heaven.

